# Parametric Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, parametric

i have a question on parametric.. The question states

> A vector equation $(x,y) = (2,-1) + t(3,2)$. Write as a parametric equation. Show a table with x,y values. Sketch a picture of vector equations. Show at least 4 points.

I don't understand how to do this, this is a test review question, so i have to know this to get prepared for test day after tomorrow. Please help, thankyou

Comment: add some more tags

Comment: What would you suggest @DeNiSkA ? Im in precalculus so precalc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can plug values in for $t$ in order to get $(x,y)$.  For example, using $t=1$ you get
$$
(x,y) = (2,-1)+1(3,2) = (5,1)
$$
Or, you can write the expressions for $x$ and $y$ independently as
$$
x = 2+3t
$$
$$
y=-1+2t
$$

Comment: Hmm tables?.... Graph?

Comment: You can easily create a table for values of $x$ and $y$ given $t$.  Have you learned how to graph a point given $(x,y)$ coordinates?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. My Fault. Thanks a lot Jed. (I was just bieng a douche...)

Comment: Is the persons anwser right here? Im skeptical... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798868/parametric-equations-problem

Comment: @Dsafds Jacob Austin's answer to that question is entirely correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thankyou very much kind sir!