# Maximum Height is giving me negative

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, parametric

Hey guys for this parametric equations its giving me negative Question is:

> A dart is thrown from a point 5 feet above the ground with an inital velocity of 58 ft/sec and angle of elvation of 41∘. Assume the onnly force acting on the dart is gravity. What is the maximum height reached by the dart? When and will the dart hit the ground? **SHOW ALL WORK.**

So what i did was

$x_t = 58 \frac{ft}{sec} * \cos(41^\circ)*t$

$y_t = -16t^2 + 58 * \sin(41^\circ)$

a When does ball land)
$-16t^2 + 58*\sin(41^\circ) * t = 0$ 
$t = 2.38sec$

b Where will it hit ground)

$x_t = 58 \frac{ft}{sec} \cos(41^\circ)*t$

$= 58 \frac{ft}{sec} \cos(41^\circ) * 2.38$

$=104.18$ ft far

All above i got correct im preety sure.. But for getting Max Height i dont get it right somehow i get negative. Im not doing it corectly?:

$y_t = -16t^2 + 58 * \sin(41^\circ)*t = 0$

$=-16(2.38^2) + 57 * \sin(41^\circ)*2.38$

And then when you solve.. it gives you negative.. Im confused here.. how i solve max height?

**Remeber I am in Precalculus NOT Calculus**

### Equations(In my notes..)

[image]

### Examples

[image]

[image]

### EDIT

Ok for MAX Height what i did was take this

$y_t = -16*t^2 + 58 * \sin(41^\circ)*t=0$

When i put in calculator its fine... i get 22.055 but i remembereed the 5... So now i have to go back to finding T:

$-16t^2 + 58* \sin(41^\circ) * t + 5 = 0$

When i tried to do that.. i get wierrrrd squarerrots and stuff.. Im not sure im right

Comment: Somone Please Anwser before i freak out

Comment: You have neglected the initial y elevation of 5 ft, also the y equation is a parabola, the max/min of a parabola occurs at the vertex

Comment: That was not it @Dan . And i already solved it now

Comment: Yes it's true the initial elevation makes no difference in this case, it is however proper to include it

Comment: Lol @Dan your right

Comment: Now i dont know how to do it... @Dan

Comment: So you write down the parabola obtained for the y part, identify a,b and c. The vertex occurs at $t=\frac{-b}{2a}$ this is the time where y is maximum. Second the initial elevation means that your time to hit the ground is wrong, this doesn't affect the time calculated for max height but does affect the height you find

Comment: @Dan i edited question.. can u respond fast please? i gtg sleep . thanks a lot btw

Comment: I'll write up a coherent answer taking into account precalculus knowledge so you can read it when you get up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will begin where you write your two equations of interest now including the initial height information in y:

\begin{array}{l}
x_t = 58 (\text{ ft/s})\cos{(41^{\circ})} t \\
y_t = -16 (\text{ ft}/\text{s}^2) t^2 + 58 (\text{ ft/s})\sin{(41^{\circ})} t
 +5 \text{ ft}
\end{array}

To find the time to hit the ground we set the second equation equal to zero and solve

$$
y_t = -16 (\text{ ft}/\text{s}^2) t^2 + 58 (\text{ ft/s})\sin{(41^{\circ})} t
 +5 \text{ ft} = 0
$$

This is quickly solved via quadratic formula

$$
t = \frac{- 58\sin(41^{\circ}) \pm \sqrt{(58\sin(41^{\circ}))^2 - 4 (-16)(5)}}{2(-16)} \approx 2.503 \text{ s}
$$

There are two roots but typically we reject negative answers for t.

I will leave the maximum distance calculation up to you as you were doing it right but with the wrong time.

As for the max height calculation, we recognize the equation for y as a parabola. From algebra we know that the max/min of a parabola occurs at the vertex. The expression for the vertex is given by (for y):
$$
t = -\frac{b}{2a} = -\frac{58\sin(41^{\circ})}{2(-16)} \approx 1.189 \text{ s}
$$

We now take this time and plug it back into the equation for y to obtain the maximum height. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Dan I love your anwser but. are you sure that t bieng 1.189 is right? And like the quad is right? Im just asking.

Comment: As far as I can tell yes, I even ran the parabola through wolframalpha just to be sure. This answer is based purely on algebra knowledge with very little physics applied

Comment: Ok Dan! your my second math bro after N.F Taussig :) . Do you mind making sure if another question's anwser i asked is right? If you can.

Comment: If you link to the question I'll give it a look, although where I am it's also pretty late at night

Comment: I couldnt understand what the cartesian equation, and vector equation he is saying is right.. he makes it complicated. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798868/parametric-equations-problem ... Yea its getting preety late, parents allowing me to stay for math reasons...

Comment: Yeah looks fine the provided answer, a vector equation is simply an equation written in vector format ie as one vector usually $r(t) = \langle x(t), y(t) \rangle$ the Cartesian is usually obtained by eliminating t, so solve either x or y for t and sub into the other.

Comment: i mean my question is what is the cartestion equation and vector equation to that problem.. i dont know what the actual anwser to the problem is..

Comment: The answer given looks correct as in those look like the answers to me and that's how I would have written them.

Comment: Ok Thankyou Dan! Your My Second Math Bro :)

Comment: No problem good luck on your test/review

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a full grasp of all the kinematics equations (this seems to be a basic physics problem). We will use this in this approach.

(a) Use $v_{f}^{2} = v_{i}^{2} + 2a\Delta y,$ where $v_{i}$ and $v_{f}$ are initial and final (vertical) velocities, respectively, $a$ is acceleration, and $\Delta y$ is the vertical displacement.

At the maximum height, the dart has $0$ vertical velocity (it is changing directions - up to down). Since gravity is the only force acting on the dart, use $a = -g = -32$ feet per second squared (up is the positive direction). Further, we know that $v_{i}$ must be $58\sin(41).$ Solving, we have
$$\Delta y = \frac{v_{f}^{2} - v_{i}^{2}}{2a}$$
$$= \frac{0 - (58\sin(41))^{2}}{2 * -32}$$
$$= 23 \text{ft}.$$

This means that the maximum height is $5 + 23 = \boxed{28 \text{ft}}.$

You seem to have figured out the other parts.